# How to susbstitute variable attribute value in CHEF

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

Use Case,

we are trying to automate the creation of a directory using script which are stored in the script directory and the recipe call's the script once it is copied to the node's /tmp directory.

```
attributereplacement/
├── Berksfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── attributes
    └── default.rb
├── chefignore
├── files
│   └── default
      └── unix.sh
├── metadata.rb
├── recipes

└── default.rb
├── spec
│       ├── spec_helper.rb
│       └── unit
│           └── recipes
│               └── default_spec.rb
└── test
└── integration
    └── default
        └── default_test.rb
```

`in the Unix.sh under files directory we have the following`

`mkdir /tmp/'#{default['main']['a2']}'`
mkdir '/tmp/'#{default['main']['a2']}'
"mkdir /tmp/'#{default['main']['a2']}'"`

Under the Attribute directory we have the following
    node.default['main']['a2'] = "MY_DIR"

Under the recipes we have the following:

```
cookbook_file '/tmp/unix.sh' do        
  source 'unix.sh'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

execute 'script' do
  command './tmp/unix.sh'
end
```

The cookbook completes execution but instead of it creating a directory called "MY_DIR" it simply creates a directory called --> 
    #{default['main']['a2']}

Is it possible to pass the attribute values to a script or is there another way to fix this issue.

NOTE: I understand we can create a a file/directory using CHEF resources but I'm more interested in doing this through scripts  as we have another use case to achieve which is just similar to passing attribute values to a script which will actually be pulled from the attribute values defined in the attributes.rb file

Answer (score 1):

Use a template resource instead of cookbook_file

```
template '/tmp/unix.sh' do
  source 'unix.sh.erb'
  variables (dir: node['main']['a2'] )
  owner 'root'
  ‎group 'root'
  ‎mode '0755' 
end
```

Create template unix.sh.erb inside templates/default inside cookbook root directory with contents like this

`mkdir /tmp/<%= dir %>`